# css show images of all same size in a list

Tags: css

I try to put this html:

```
<ol>
    <li><span><img src="http://l.yimg.com/us.yimg.com/i/mesg/emoticons7/102.gif" width="10ex" height="1em"/></span>Something</li>
    <li><span><img src="http://www.smallbusinessfriends.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/cms.jpg" width="10ex" height="1em"/></span>Another thing</li>
</ol>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kritya/6hFHG/)

When i put a smaller image it shows fine but when i try to put a larger image it doesnt works ?
Why so ?
And how can i fix this ?

Comment: Read the qustion before commenting :O

Comment: "try to put larger images it doesn't works" makes no sense to me. I am glad someone could understand it though.

Comment: If u open the demo i dont guess u will have any doubt :O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't declare the sizes for the image in the html, but rather, in the CSS.

**[See this Example](http://jsfiddle.net/RikudoSennin/6hFHG/4/)**

```
span img {
    width: 10px;
    height: 1em;
}
```

Actually, you can even drop the `<span>` and have the `<img>` to be `display: inline-block;` instead.

Comment: If u zoom into it u see that the bigger pic i a bit above the text. How di i fix that ?

Comment: I don't see that. Please submit a screenshot of the problem.

Comment: Sorry but i am on a mobile atm i cant. But i guess i can see it. Maybe fault of andro browser :D

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kritya/6hFHG/8/ see this as i increased the size it becomes clear that it is below

Comment: I'm on mobile suit too so it'll have to wait

Comment: @kritya it's the image itself. It has a transparent line on the bottom, But take a regular image (a red square) and you'll see that it's exactly in-line with the text.

Answer (score 1):

In your css:

```
img { max-height: 15px; }
```

something like this? or if you prefer:

```
li img { max-height: 15px; }
```

if you target older browsers, you should use height instead of max-height.

As Rikudo said ypu can use 1em for size :)

Comment: But when i do so and zoom in u see that pic is a biy above the text. How to fix ?